# getChildren().removeAll() does not remove nodes

Tags: java, javafx

I have the following JavaFX app. I expect that each time I click the button, `count` increases and the button is replaced with a new instance that shows the new count. But instead, the previous button is still visible. Why doesn't calling `pane.getChildren().removeAll()` seem to work?

```java
public class App extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
  }

  private int count;

  public void start(Stage stage) {
    count = 0;

    var root = new VBox();
    var button = createButton(root);
    root.getChildren().add(button);

    var scene = new Scene(root, 640, 480);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }

  private void onButtonClicked(final Pane root) {
    count += 1;
    
    root.getChildren().removeAll(); // <-- This doesn't work?
    root.getChildren().add(createButton(root));
  }

  private Button createButton(final Pane root) {
    var button = new Button("Clicked " + count + " times");
    button.setOnAction((_event) -> onButtonClicked(root));
  }
}
```

Comment: I found lots of threads asking similar questions, but none of them were highly upvoted or helpful in my situation. What I got wrong was ultimately a pretty silly and easy-to-fix mistake, so I figured I'd write up my findings to help whoever runs into this next!

Comment: While adding/removing elements from a layout is occasionally useful, it looks like overkill in this example.  Are you aware that you can just update the Button with Button.setText()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`removeAll()` doesn't clear the children. Instead, it expects to receive an argument list of specific `Node` instances, and it then removes those specific children while leaving all others untouched. Calling it with no arguments doesn't remove anything, by specification! [Here are the relevant docs.](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.base/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html#removeAll(E...))

Are you looking for `clear()` instead? That function removes all the elements from the children `ObservableList`. ([Relevant docs.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#clear())) You'd want to make this change:

```java
private void onButtonClicked(final Pane root) {
  count += 1;
    
  root.getChildren().clear(); // This does the trick!
  root.getChildren().add(createButton(root));
}
```

Comment: Note: If you want to do this in one line, see [`ObservableList::setAll(E...)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.base/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html#setAll(E...)).

Comment: A nice thing about using `setAll`, is that it will trigger just a single list change event, rather than two if you clear the list and then add an element (or many more if you add a lot of elements one by one).